# No such file or directory when executing script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder bin/bash in which i've put this script:     mal_test.sh

```
if grep 'php \$[a-zA-Z]*=.as.;' "$1" >/dev/null
then
    "!!! $1 is malware!!!"
else
    "    $1 is fine."
fi
```

I run the following command from a different directory:

```
find -type f -exec ./mal_test.sh '{}' ';'
```

But i get an error find: `./mal_test` - No such file or directory

I guess the script is being interpreted as a file...what do i fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh my... The first line was not supposed to go in the script :)

Comment: try to use the complete path for your script. Example: /home/xx/is-it-malware.sh

Comment: Since you claim the error is saying `./mal_test` rather than `./mal_test.sh`, did you forget to specify the `.sh`?

Comment: your find command is missing the search path of the file to be found.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few anomalies …

<strike>1) You are using extended regular expression in your grep. So you should be using `-E option`.</strike>

<strike>2) In your find command instead of quoting the `';'` do `\;`</strike>

3) Since you placed the script in your bin/bash directory, make sure that path is added to your PATH environment variable. Other way is to provide the entire path where you script resides.

4) There are no `echo` statements in your `if then else` loop.

5) In your find command you need to provide the path where you want to find the files. Use `.` for current directory. eg `find . -type f -exec ./script.sh {} \;`

I made the following changes to your script *(you can add your own RegEx)*. This is what I get -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

if grep -E '[a-zA-Z]*' ${1}  >/dev/null
then
  echo  "!!! $1 is malware!!!"
else
  echo   "    $1 is fine."
fi
```

Output:

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ find . -type f -exec ./script.sh {} \;
    ./.mp3 is fine.
    ./1 is fine.
!!! ./a.sh is malware!!!
!!! ./ab.sed is malware!!!
!!! ./b.sh is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/GTP_Identifier.sh is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/GTP_Parser.sh is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/split.pl is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/T20111017153052.NEW is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/T20111025172411.NEW is malware!!!
!!! ./backup/T20111107193400.NEW is malware!!!
```

Comment: Not convinced about the 'grep -E' comment; it looks like a BRE to me, and regular grep should be fine.  The missing echoes were a major problem.  There's no harm using `';'` instead of `\;`, either - both work (and I tend to use quotes in preference to backslashes).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler!! Sorry about that. I have recently started working on *nix system and still learning. Appreciate your comments. :) +1 (Have updated the answer)